# Padding Image to middle of text and push down all inline elements

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to lower the image to the middle of text inside of anchor element

```
<td width="356px" style="padding:0px;">
<a style="color:#094072;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;'" href="">
<span>testttttt</span>
 <img src="/test.jpg" style="padding-top:5px;">
</a>
</td>
```

as you can see the Image has `style="padding-top:5px;"` but instead of lowering the image only, it's pushing the text too.
I can't use float because its suppose to work on email clients.

Thanks for any help

Baaroz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `vertical-align: middle;` to your image...

```
<td width="356px" style="padding:0px;">
  <a style="color:#094072;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;" href="">
    <span>testttttt</span>
    <img src="/test.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
  </a>
</td>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JyyFB/)

Comment: can you explain this behavior

Comment: The default behavior is for the text to align with the bottom of an image.  Or in other words...  the bottom of the image will be aligned with the baseline of the surrounding text.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: just set the align attribute for you img element: align="middle"

```
<td width="356px" style="padding:0px;">
<a style="color:#094072;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;'" href="">
<span >testttttt</span>
 <img src="/test.jpg" style="padding-top:5px;" align="middle">
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: then I loose the inline style

Comment: @baaroz, edited now, use the align attribute on the img element. Set it to middle.

Comment: thanks Charles, I will accept @Balbin answer as he post the right answer first but you get vote up

Comment: @baaroz, lol, cool beans, just wasn't understanding initially. Mine is a value for the align attribute for<img> and his is for the style attribute, both different, but both work :-)